# How to generate a SpatVector from SpatExtent in R terra?

Tags: r, terra

Does anybody know if there is a built-in function in R `terra` to generate a SpatVector polygon from an `ext` object, please?

```
library(terra)
# A SpatExtent object
ext1 <- ext(c(-74.5, -72.5, 9.5,  12.0))
```

How I manually created the coordinates of the polygon vertices

```
box_coords <- rbind(
   c(ext1[1], ext1[3]),
   c(ext1[2], ext1[3]),
   c(ext1[2], ext1[4]),
   c(ext1[1], ext1[4]),
   c(ext1[1], ext1[3])
)
box_coords
#      [,1] [,2]
#[1,] -74.5  9.5
#[2,] -72.5  9.5
#[3,] -72.5 12.0
#[4,] -74.5 12.0
#[5,] -74.5  9.5
```

How I convert the coordinate into a SpatVector

```
box1 <- vect(box_coords, type = "lines")
```

The way I'd like it to be, but that doesn't work

```
box1 <- vect(ext1)
```

Comment: Can you show how you created the `ext1` object

Comment: The `terra` documentation says: "## with an extent
`e <- ext(5.9, 6.3, 49.9, 50)
v <- vect(f, extent=e)`", but when I try that, I get an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `as.polygons`

```
library(terra)
e <- ext(-74.5, -72.5, 9.5, 12.0)
p <- as.polygons(e, crs="")
# or 
p <- as.polygons(e, crs="+proj=longlat")
```

You can also use `as.points` and `as.lines`

To get a polygon for the extent of SpatRaster or SpatVector `x` you can do

```
x <- rast()
p <- as.polygons(x, extent=TRUE)
```

The latter has the advantage that the coordinate reference system is not lost, or is less convulted than the alternative

```
p <- as.polygons(ext(x), extent=TRUE, crs=crs(x))
```

I have now added this path as well (terra 1.7-6) .

```
ve <- vect(e, crs="+proj=longlat")
```

And, to get a numeric *vector* (not a *SpatVector*) you can do

```
as.vector(e)
```